# trying to download JSON from mySQL

Tags: android, sql, json

hey there guys and girls, iv been trying to fix this problem for weeks now and carnt seem to get any help, i want the code to download a JSON file from my server and the save it to internal memory with the saveJSON() and then with the showJSON() it should display the saved JSON file and then decode it to plain text. the problems i get are around HttpResponse and the next line and also im not sure it the next section is also write where it should save the JSON file. here are the two errors im getting

```
Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

and

```
Error saving string null.pointer
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String storyObj = "";
Object json = null;
HttpEntity entity = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //button that saves the file from mySQL
    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveJson();             
        }
    });

    //Button that opens the file from InternalMemory
    Button open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);
    open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openJson();             
        }
    });


//end of onCreate() 
}


//saveJson pull a JSON file from mySQl server then saves that file in its JSON type eg .json
public void saveJson(){
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);


    try{
        //connects to mySQL
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //captures the response
        entity = response.getEntity();

    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        Object json = entity;
        String FILENAME = "story.json";
        //gives file name
        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        //creates new StreamWriter
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
        //writes json with file name story.json
        writer.write((Integer) json);
        writer.flush();
        //closes writer
        writer.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error saving string "+e.toString());
    }

//end of saveJson()
}

private char[] Object(Object json2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public void openJson(){
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);



    try{
        FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("story.json");

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInput, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            fileInput.close();
            storyObj = strBuilder.toString();

    }catch(IOException e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error building string "+e.toString());
    }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(storyObj);
        String storyNames = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            storyNames += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("story_name") +"\n";
        }
        test.setText(storyNames);

    }catch(JSONException e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error returning string "+e.toString());
    }
    return;
//and of openJson() 
}




//end of class body    
}
```

and here is my xml manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.game"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<users-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
<users-permission   android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:debuggable="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you able to access the web API from android browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this really is your Manifest file, the error is obvious .The tags should not be `use[r]s-permission`, but `uses-permission`:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
```

Now you wouldn't have access to internet, and thus the error. If you switch to using an IDE like Eclipse and use autocomplete you will avoid such errors from the very beginning, but furthermore the IDE will underline this mistakes as warnings.

**EDIT**: About the error you get - you are trying to cast the entity of the response directly to an Integer. This will always fail, because Integer is not superclass of `HttpEntity`. You need to read the contents of the entity in a `String` and then parse the contents of the string to integer:

```
InputStream entityStream = entity.getcontent();
StringBuilder entityStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesReadCount;
while ((bytesReadCount = entityStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    entityStringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesReadCount));
}
String entityString = entityStringBuilder.toString();
Integer responseInteger = Integer.valueOf(entityString);
```

this is not highly optimized, but does the job. From then on you can use the `responseInteger` value as you like . However if you want to do `writer.write` you will need `String` value, not `Integer`. Thus I recommend you to use `entityString`.

Comment: Error saving string java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity this is now the only error i have thanks boris i think you have helped me before

Comment: You are trying to skip several steps while reading the response. Please mind the edit of my answer.

Comment: hey boris i have eclipse but missed that one some how in the manifest

Comment: boris iv fixed the INTERNET problem but still have a problem with it writing the file to internal memory

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry the edit of my answer took me a bit more than what I expected. Now it is there, though.

Comment: you will also need the permission to write to sd card:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: thanks boris for your time, will i still be able to seperate the json later after it is downloaded and saved to memory?

Comment: You have a string representation of your json. You write it to storage and can read it whenever. You always can parse it. As for parsing of the json I highly recommend using gson library: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

You inserted the permission wrong. It has to be something like this

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

You used:

```
<users-permission ...
```

Where do you get the String nullpointer?

Comment: between Object json = entity; and writer.close();

Comment: it doesnt seem to save the JSON properly, is entity the object i would be saving?