# saving a json file to internal memory

Tags: android, entity, save, internal

hey there guys and girls i have this code that should download a json object and then save it to internal memory, i keep getting stuck here

```
    try{
        //connects to mySQL
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //captures the response
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        is = entity.getContent();
        String FILENAME = "story.json";
        //gives file name
        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        //creates new StreamWriter
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
        //writes json with file name story.json
        writer.write(is);
        writer.flush();
        //closes writer
        writer.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error saving string "+e.toString());
    }
```

i keep getting erros on writer.write(is); eclipse asks me to change it to an int, what would be the best way to code from the line

```
entity = response.getEntity();
```

???

here is my full code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String storyObj = "";
Object json = null;
HttpEntity entity = null;
InputStream is = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //button that saves the file from mySQL
    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveJson();             
        }
    });

    //Button that opens the file from InternalMemory
    Button open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);
    open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openJson();             
        }
    });


//end of onCreate() 
}


//saveJson pull a JSON file from mySQl server then saves that file in its JSON type eg .json
public void saveJson(){
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);


    try{
        //connects to mySQL
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //captures the response
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        is = entity.getContent();
        String FILENAME = "story.json";
        //gives file name
        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        //creates new StreamWriter
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
        //writes json with file name story.json
        writer.write(is);
        writer.flush();
        //closes writer
        writer.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error saving string "+e.toString());
    }

//end of saveJson()
}

private char[] Object(Object json2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public void openJson(){
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);



    try{
        FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("story.json");

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInput, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            fileInput.close();
            storyObj = strBuilder.toString();

    }catch(IOException e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error building string "+e.toString());
    }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(storyObj);
        String storyNames = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            storyNames += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("story_name") +"\n";
        }
        test.setText(storyNames);

    }catch(JSONException e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error returning string "+e.toString());
    }
    return;
//and of openJson() 
}




//end of class body    
}
```

hope you can help me with this, been taking so long to get it to work!!!

added extra code from boris... is this where i put the code ?

```
    try{
        //connects to mySQL
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //captures the response
        entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream entityStream = entity.getcontent();
        StringBuilder entityStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesReadCount;
        while ((bytesReadCount = entityStream(read(buffer)) > 0)) {
            entityStringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesReadCount));
        }
        String entityString = entityStringBuilder.toString();
        Integer responseInteger = Integer.valueOf(entityString);
    }catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
```

if it is i get an error on read

Comment: Where/how do you declare the `is` object?

Comment: above onCreate() with InputStream is = null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is weird case, I edited my previous answer to fix this problem of yours. However: another  question was asked, so here goes this portion of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9451405/1108032):

About the error you get - you are trying to cast the entity of the response directly to an Integer. This will always fail, because Integer is not superclass of `HttpEntity`. You need to read the contents of the entity in a `String` and then parse the contents of the string to integer:

```
InputStream entityStream = entity.getcontent();
StringBuilder entityStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesReadCount;
while ((bytesReadCount = entityStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    entityStringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesReadCount));
}
String entityString = entityStringBuilder.toString();
writer.wrtie(entityString);
```

this is not highly optimized, but does the job. From then on you can use the `responseInteger` value as you like . However if you want to do `writer.write` you will need `String` value, not `Integer`. Thus I recommend you to use `entityString`.

Comment: boris i added code to my question is this write? what i have done?

Comment: Yes you can do it that way no problem. Also you can do it insetad of the line

    try 
    {
       is = entity.getContent(); // this line.

Comment: Do you? It might be that I made some error (keep in mind that most of my answers I write out of top of my head without trying them in real, which means I might have done some stupid syntatic error). Please tell me what is your error.

Comment: @daniel ah the stupid syntatic error I was speaking of: I had a brace instead of a dot. Try it out now.

Comment: sorry boris where does the . go at ((bytesReadCount = entityStream(read (buffer)) > 0))

Comment: Error in http connection java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '[{"story_name":"Story One"},{"story_name":"Story Two"},{"story_name":"Story Three"},{"story_name":"Story Four"},{"story_name":"Story Five"},{"story_name":"Story Six"}]' as integer this is now my new error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8230/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-daniel)

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
package com.android.test.CacheDemo;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CachingDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private static String URL="http://bhaskar1.cntdy.mobi/punjabkesari/appdetails/sectiondetails.json";
    private static String FILE_NAME = "CachedResponse";
    private Button startAPICallButton;
    private Button retrieveFromCacheButton;

    /* view lifecycle methods*/
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.initializeComponents();
    }
    /*overriden methods*/
    public void onClick(View clickedView)
    {
        if(clickedView == this.startAPICallButton)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Making the API call... Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.makeAPICall();
        }
        else if(clickedView == this.retrieveFromCacheButton)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Retrieving data from the cache!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.retrieveStuffFromCache();
        }
    }
    /* private methods*/
    private void initializeComponents()
    {
        this.startAPICallButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.start_api_call_button);
        this.startAPICallButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.retrieveFromCacheButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.retrieve_cache_button);
        this.retrieveFromCacheButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void makeAPICall()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    //download the json onto the device.
                    URL url = new URL(CachingDemoActivity.URL);
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    //read the data and store it in a byte array first.
                    //dont use this code for big json file 
                    //as long as its a json and not very long, this will work just fine!!!
                    InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int readByte = 0;
                    //read the bytes one-by-one from the inputstream to the buffer.
                    while(true)
                    {
                        readByte = inStream.read();
                        if(readByte == -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        byteOutStream.write(readByte);
                    }
                    byteOutStream.flush();
                    inStream.close();
                    byteOutStream.close();
                    byte[] response = byteOutStream.toByteArray();
                    //now response byte array is the complete json in the biary form. We will save this stuff to file.
                    File cacheDir = CachingDemoActivity.this.getCacheDir();
                    File jsonFile = new File(cacheDir, FILE_NAME);
                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(jsonFile);
                    //write the whole data into the file
                    for(int i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
                    {
                        outStream.write(response[i]);
                    }
                    android.util.Log.e("status - ","API call is complete!!");
                    //this should do the trick of saving all the stuff in the file with file name CachedResponse!!
                    //let see if we can retrieve the stuff!!!
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void retrieveStuffFromCache()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    File jsonFile = new File(CachingDemoActivity.this.getCacheDir(), FILE_NAME);
                    FileInputStream fInStream = new FileInputStream(jsonFile);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int readByte = 0;
                    while(true)
                    {
                        readByte = fInStream.read();
                        if(readByte == -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        byteOutStream.write(readByte);
                    }
                    fInStream.close();
                    byteOutStream.flush();
                    byteOutStream.close();
                    byte[] retrievedStringData = byteOutStream.toByteArray();
                    String originalJson = new String(retrievedStringData);
                    android.util.Log.e("json - ", originalJson);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```